# How to create an epub with drmed?

Tags: epub, drm

I want to crate an epub file with drm , so when I open it with adobe edition reader or ibooks, it will reports it's drmed .

Here is some refs:
http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-ocf.html#app-schema-encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to programmatically add (Adobe) DRM to EPUB files, you need to purchase an Adobe Active Content Server license from Adobe (and it is not cheap!): http://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/content-server.html

If you are just interested in having one single EPUB file DRM'ed, probably the best/easiest/cheapest way is to distribute it through a platform that will add the DRM for you (usually, for a cut on the sell revenues).

BTW, why do you want to add the (Adobe) DRM? It can be easily removed with one click, and it is an absolute hassle for legitimate buyers. Adding a watermark might be a better alternative, if you are concerned about illegal sharing.

Comment: I just want a single drmed file and when open it in iBooks reporst an "drmed file " .

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot add yourself the Adobe DRM to an EPUB file, and sell that file to different customers (e.g. through your web site or whatever). So, either: 1. you buy an ACS license from Adobe and set your selling web site up to generate the required .ACSM files for your customers, or 2. you choose to distribute your ebook through a platform that gives you the choice of adding the Adobe DRM to the copies sold. (In this second case, the platform has an ACS license, and manages the generation of the .ACSM files, one for each different customer.)